# Using a user defined function inside a procedure with a cursor on oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to insert a function that defines a value(salary) into a procedure. that value needs to be inserted into a column in a table(employees).

All the other values that are going to be inserted into the table(employees) are being defined by a cursor(in the procedure) that is extracting data from another table, however the last value(salary) is not on the cursor, but is defined by a function I created instead. How could I add it into my procedure so that the data from my cursor is put into their respective columns and then the function creates the data for the last column of the table?

My procedure is

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE migratestuff
IS
CURSOR names_cursor
  IS
    select substr(staff.name, 0, instr(staff.name, ' ') - 1) as firstname,
          substr(staff.name, instr(staff.name, ' ')         + 1) as lastname,
      lower(concat(substr(staff.name, 0,1), substr(staff.name, instr(staff.name, ' ')         + 1)||'@mail.com')) as emails,
      date_created
    from staff;
employee_rec names_cursor%rowtype;
counter number := 1;
BEGIN
  FOR employee_rec IN names_cursor
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO employee
      (fname, lname,Email,emp_ID,hire_date,salary
      ) VALUES
      (employee_rec.firstname, employee_rec.lastname,employee_rec.Emails,counter,
       employee_rec.Date_created,SALARYFUNCTIONRESULTHERE
      );
 commit;   
 counter := counter +1;
  END LOOP;
end;
```

My function if it helps(This is the function that will give the value salary needs in the insert statement):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
FUNCTION salary_function(
      in_date IN DATE)
    RETURN NUMBER
  IS
    salary_out NUMBER(5);
  BEGIN
    IF to_char(in_date, 'YYYY') = '2013' THEN
      salary_out               :=7000;
    ELSE
      IF to_char(in_date, 'YYYY') = '2014' THEN
        salary_out               := 6000;
      ELSE
        IF to_char(in_date, 'YYYY') = '2015' THEN
          salary_out               := 5000;
        END IF;
      END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN salary_out;
  END;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What will happen if you write this: VALUES
      (employee_rec.firstname, employee_rec.lastname,employee_rec.Emails,counter,
       employee_rec.Date_created,salary_function(aDateVariable)
      );

Comment: It ignores the statement and it tells me that the column is not allowed there.

Comment: Well in that case you can do it the hard way :). Store the result of the function in a varchar2 variable. Then create a varchar2 representation of the call using the variable and run EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

Comment: With result do you mean that I should call the function with a value and then store and use that as a variable in the procedure? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Use `insert . . . select` instead:

```
INSERT INTO employee(fname, lname, Email, emp_ID, hire_date, salary)
  SELECT employee_rec.firstname, employee_rec.lastname, employee_rec.Emails, counter,
         employee_rec.Date_created, SALARYFUNCTIONRESULTHERE
  FROM dual;
```

Comment: I got an error saying that I'm missing the right parenthesis after my first value inside the statement. 
Here:  employee_rec.firstname,

I got this:
Error(32,31): PL/SQL: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: @LightningBolt . . . The answer was missing the closing paren on the column list for the `insert`.

Comment: I got the salary function as an invalid identifier, does this mean that I need to declare it?

Comment: @LightningBolt . . . You need to define/declare it before you execute this code.